# What's the name of the image that looks like several curly brackets together?

Tags: style-identification

Like the one shown on the RSVP design. Thank you.

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/194569646371938464/

[image]

Comment: Personally I just call it a bracket frame, though there MUST be a more technical term :)

Comment: @Jenna 43 million Google hits kind of agree with you.

Answer (score 7):

**[Bracket Frame.](http://gog.is/bracket+frame)**

Because thanks to @Bakabaka, I am sure that Google agrees :)

Comment: When adding a link to a Google search the best way to do it is `http://gog.is/keyword+keyword+keyword`. With your previous link, my browser flashed a page of incomprehensible gibberish before it correctly interpreted the link. Just a friendly and hopefully useful tip.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the edit :) friendly advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason "bracket frame" just isn't cutting it for me. Seems like a more stylized derivative of the [barbed quatrefoil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatrefoil#Barbed_quatrefoil).

[image: barbed quatrefoil]

It's killing me that I can't find a more "official" name for it, but the first thing I thought of was [this episode of 99% Invisible](http://99percentinvisible.org/episode/the-fancy-shape/) from a few weeks back. Maybe someone else feels like digging into *The Grammar of Ornament* for more context.

Or just stick with bracket frame.

Comment: I was also shocked...surely there must be something more technical!!